# Why do we need a connection pool for a standalone application?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, connection-pooling

I need to know why we need a connection pool for a standalone application. According to my knowledge, a standalone application needs only one database connection instance. That's why we use the singleton pattern while creating the connection object using JDBC. So what's the use of having a connection pool for a standalone application? If I am using a connection pool, do I need to specify the max size as 1? Here I am trying to use the CP30 connection pool with native Hibernate.

Comment: Are you able to describe what this standalone application is supposed to do ? 
I could imagine it works with multiple threads (workers) and they you definitely need a connection pool.
If you use the CP30 connection pool use the default setup until you realise it does not work for you.

Comment: No it has only one user @TraychoIvanov

Comment: Even if you have one user it could need to access database multiple times, which means better to reuse connection from the pool. I would recommend using it. Creating a new connection is very expensive operation while with the pool you get it directly and reduce the effort.

Comment: There won't be be re creation of connection objects , because of the Singleton pattern @TraychoIvanov

Comment: Well, in this case you has to manage yourself creation, closing of connection, handing database connection outages etc. If your application is just executed and ends it is fine otherwise I would use a pool with size 1. If you think the pool is overhead, don't use it :)

Comment: You ask "why we need", which assumes it is somehow required to use a connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

I agree you have a stand-alone application, but that does not mean, you always need to use a Singleton design pattern. How about a single application spinning up multiple threads and each thread connecting to the database. In that case, Singleton won't be of any help, and you should implement connection pool, you are gracefully handling the db operations.

Connection pool and applications (stand-alone or distributed), are related to some extent, but it majorly depends on the use case. Suppose you are working on a stand-alone desktop based application, which is a simple CRUD one, in that case, I agree you need not implement connection pool, but in case we are talking about multiple user, and that too parallel, I think we should always leverage connection pool.

Not sure what your use-case talks about, but generalizing the statement, "Stand-alone application, does not need connection pooling", does not stand true always.

Comment: So when it comes to standalone application with one user , I can implement the application without a connection pool.For a moment if I use a connection pool for this scenario also won't it be useless to have a multiple connection objects which already created by connection pool with no use case.I mean if my connection pool created 5 instances then 4 instances will be useless because of the above scenario.

Comment: "Multi-threaded applications need a connection pool" does not hold true always either ;)

Comment: @Gimby, Might not always stand true, but more often than not we would, but majorly what I wanted to highlight is, a stand-alone application, does not mean "NO CONNECTION POOLING"

Comment: Even single user, single threaded applications could benefit from a connection pool. It is not impossible for a long running user application to lose connection with the database. Using a connection pool and only obtaining a connection for a unit of work will allow you to handle connection failures more gracefully than having a single connection initialized at the start and trying to use that throughout the runtime of the application.

Answer (score 1):

A major reason for using a connection pool is that it makes it easier for your application to recover in case the connection goes bad. The only time I would not use a connection pool was if it was acceptable for the program to fail if the connection stopped working. An example could be a very simple batch job that executed one transaction and the job framework running it would retry it if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of using a connection pool is usually insignificant.

Your data access layer does not need to know whether it's being called from a standalone application or, say, a multithreaded web application.  So there's a good case for always using connection pooling, which doesn't hurt in the first case and is probably necessary in the second.